# Is there wsdl to ruby proxy code generators for savon or handsoap gems?

Tags: ruby, proxy, wsdl, handsoap, savon

Based on their design philosophy, it sounds like they want gem users to hand code ruby proxy classes. I still feel that they could have provided generators.

Any suggestions on how to generate maintainable ruby proxy classes for savon or handsoap?

Answer (score 1):

Handsoap comes with a generator. It's documented at: [github.com/unwire/handsoap/wiki/Recommendations](https://github.com/unwire/handsoap/wiki/Recommendations)